# Sticky scroll with active class on navigation items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a sticky scroll navigation that changes the active class as it passes each section on the page. It is a little buggy though...

heres my jquery code:

```
var s = $("#page-nav"),
    pos = s.position();                    
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
    s.addClass("stick");
    $('.main').css('margin-top', '60px');
  } else {
    s.removeClass("stick"); 
    $('.main').removeAttr('style');
  }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('.linky').each(function (event) {
    id = $(this).attr('href');
    if (y >= $(id).offset().top) {
      $('.linky').not(this).removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });

});
//page nav
$("#page-nav li a").click(function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); 
  $("#page-nav li a").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  goToByScroll($(this).attr("href").replace("#", ""));           
});

function goToByScroll(id){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},
        'slow');
}
```

And here is a working example over at [codepen](http://codepen.io/robbo/pen/mihIj/)

How can I improve my javascript so that is performs a little smoother. As you can see when you  click a link it still thinks it is within that section and the active class flickers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was that you were setting the `active` class when you click an link and also when you move. What I did was to remove the class handling from the `click` event handler and let the `scroll` handler take care of everything. This way, there is no flicker. Here you have an updated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lsuDz).

```
$("#page-nav li a").click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    goToByScroll($(this).attr("href").replace("#", ""));           
});
```

If this solution is not good enough for you, tell me and I'll think something more sophisticated.

New working solution [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CHgiJ/).

Basically, I created a variable that indicates whether you have clicked a link or not. If you have, then the `scroll` handler won't change CSS classes (avoiding the flicker). Then, in the `complete` handler of your `animate` function, I set it to false again (allowing for class changes as you scroll):

```
var s = $("#page-nav"),
    pos = s.position(),
    linkClicked = false;   

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
    s.addClass("stick");
    $('.main').css('margin-top', '60px');
  } else {
    s.removeClass("stick"); 
    $('.main').removeAttr('style');
  }
});


$(window).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('.linky').each(function (event) {
    id = $(this).attr('href');
    if (y >= $(id).offset().top) {
      if (!linkClicked) {
          $('.linky').not(this).removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
      }
    }
  });
});

//page nav
$("#page-nav li a").click(function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#page-nav li a").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  linkClicked = true;
 goToByScroll($(this).attr("href").replace("#", ""));           
});

function goToByScroll(id){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},
         'slow', function() {
             linkClicked = false;
        });
}
```

Comment: Yes that would prevent setting the active link on scroll and click. However if a section is at the bottom of the page it will never have the active class set as it'l never scroll to that point (bottom of window). Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, I've got an idea. Just give me some time.

Comment: check it now. I think this time will satisfy your needs.

Comment: Sweet, that works! I'm guessing this whole thing could be coded much cleaner?